# Is there any similar function to reverse the list in Python for ranges like in C++?

Tags: python, c++

In C++, we do `reverse(nums.begin() + 1, nums.end() - 2)` for reversing a list or vector in ranges. So, is there something like this in Python for achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing) syntax:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> l[3:6] = l[5:2:-1]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```